# Manipulate embeded IE printing settings in C#?

Tags: c#, printing

How can I adjust the printing settings of an embeded IE browser in C#?
For example I would like to hide the header and footer with page numbers and title or URL (any data that isn't part of the website which is printed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this but you have to do it though the registry. I'm guessing when you say embeded you have a C# win forms application with a browser control in it that you want to adjust settings for and so should be able to perform registry access. Have a look at the link below for more information.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/236777